# Error: Context from react-redux not found. If you are using react-redux v6 a v3.*.* version of react-redux-firebase is required

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux-firebase

When I built a simple React.js app using Redux and Firestore, the following error occurred. It requires v3.*.* version of react-redux-firebase, however, NPM doesn't support that version. The latest version is v2.4.1. Is there anyone who has already resolved the issue?

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^6.6.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.9.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
```

Visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-firebase for react-redux-firebase module.

Comment: The v.3 is currently in beta only:https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/releases. You can try to install it with `npm i react-redux-firebase@next`

Comment: Or you can install v5 of react-redux waiting for a stable v3 of react-redux-firebase : 
`npm i react-redux@5.0.7`

Comment: Thanks, Dyo. Your comment works fine on my side.